# Prevent new options being added to grub after kernel updates?

Tags: kernel, grub2, updates

Every time I new kernel update is installed to my system, it adds itself again to the boot menu. Right now my boot menu has 3 linux option, one for each kernel version.

how can I avoid that new options to be added?

Comment: Actually, as @Uri mentions in his answer, you do want the new version added in order to use it, but the old ones removed afterwards.

Comment: Do you care if the old kernels exist?   If you don't care, there are solutions that involve removing the old kernels. Or do you want (some of) them present but not displayed?

Comment: I just want to remove old versions, I do not want to keep multiple versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's not the best idea to always remove the old kernels! You may experience some bugs with the new kernel, or other problem, you can't know. Then you can boot with the previous kernel to "save the day". Without that option and with a crash (always) during the boot would render your system unusable (sure you can help with a boot CD or so). Ok, it's not so frequent, maybe I can can mention a single happening like this with me since 6 years, or so. But it's very nasty if happens. I would recommend to keep at least two versions, the newest and the one before it: you can boot the older if you experience any problem. Anyway, you can remove the old versions if you really want:
`apt-get --purge remove linux-image-...`
where the "..." means the same character-string you can see in /boot after file names initrd.img- or eg vmlinuz- so an example:
`apt-get --purge remove linux-image-2.6.35-24-generic` For sure, you can remove packages by Synaptic Package Manager as well, if you prefer GUI more than using command line.

Be careful not to remove kernel which is currently running, you can check the current one with this command: `uname -r`

And a little comment: your question is a bit misleading: you should not ask not to add new options after kernel updates, since the important thing here to have a newer, updated kernel. What you need (maybe) is to remove older ones, so it's really about removing older ones.

Comment: I asked how to remove the old kernels, the question was edited. Thanks for your response.